# How should I represent a unique super-admin privilege in a database?

Tags: database, relational-database

My project needs to have a number of administrators, out of which only one will have super-admin privileges.

What is the best way to represent this in the database?

Comment: then by definition they are not called as administrators...

Comment: @Srinivas, you can have _levels_ of administrative power. For example, admins may be able to do everything but create other admins.

Comment: Just use UniqueSuperAdmin, who doesn't want to be a UniqueSuperAdmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

Number 1: Have a column on your administrator (or user) table called `IsSuperAdmin` and have an insert/update trigger to ensure that only one has it set at any given time.

Number 2: Have a `TimestampWhenMadeSuperAdmin` column in your table. Then, in your query to figure out who it is, use something like:

```
select user_id from users
where TimestampWhenMadeSuperAdmin is not null
order by TimestampWhenMadeSuperAdmin desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Number 3/4: Put the SuperAdmin user ID into a separate table, using either the trigger or last-person-made-has-the-power approach from numbers 1 or 2.

Personally, I like number 2 since it gives you what you need without unnecessary triggers, *and* there's an audit trail as to who had the power at any given time (though not a complete audit trail since it will only store the most recent time that someone was made a SuperAdmin).

The trouble with number 1 is what to do if you just clear the current SuperAdmin. Either you have to give the power to someone else, or nobody has it. n other words, you can get yourself into a situation where there is no SuperAdmin. And number 3 and 4 just complicate things with an extra table.

Comment: Thanks! I too liked the second option.

Answer (score 2):

Use a roles/groups approach. You have a table containing all the possible roles, and then you have an *intersect* table containing the key of the user and the key of the role they belong to (there can be multiple entries per user as each user could have several roles (or belong to several groups)).

Also, don't call them *super admin* - just *admin* is fine, call the rest *power user* or something similar.

Comment: I would call them 'admin' and 'manager' (and maybe 'user' or 'registered' for regular users and 'anonymous' for the rest). But the role/group approach is in my opinion surely the most powerful one, so I recommend that.

Comment: Yes, it's a good approach but, unfortunately, doesn't address the actual question, which was how to ensure there was only one SuperAdmin at a time. As to what you call them, it's irrelevant. If you want a `DemiGodEmporerOfTheUniverse`, that's fine by me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, yet effective: UserId = 1. Your application will always know it is the SuperUser.

Comment: So you're proposing to change user IDs of people on the fly? That's likely to bugger up all sorts of relationships elsewhere :-)

Comment: ??? Not proposing to change user IDs on the fly. Application will automatically create a superuser when it is started the first time. If I am not mistaken, this is more or less the approach taken by Drupal. UserId, the first user automatically created into the database is userid 1

Comment: But if the current superadmin leaves the organization, they would have to change UserIDs for both the old (leaving) superadmin and the new (entering) superadmin. While technically achievable, it will be a lot of work to ensure ALL references to UserIDs in other tables are also updated. Similarly, most people working on the code are likely to assume that a single user always has the same UserID, and that a single UserID always refers to the same user.

Comment: That is why I said it is a "simple" approach.